# How to improve readability of stage view for matrix pipelines?

Tags: jenkins

I have a `Jenkinsfile` with the following declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('BuildAndTest') {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'CONFIG'
                        values 'Configuration A', 'Configuration B'
                    } 
                    axis {
                        name 'OPT'
                        values 'Debug', 'Release'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Build') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Do Build for ${CONFIG} - ${OPT}"
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Test') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Do Test for ${CONFIG} - ${OPT}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following stage view diagram:

[image: Stage View]

Is there any way to make this more readable? Namely, to make it clear from the column headers which configurations failed, instead of having multiple columns with the same header. Also, the *Matrix* columns seem pretty redundant to me.

Remarks:

- Jenkins version is 2.277.4
- I tried to use `${CONFIG}`/`${OPT}` in the stage names, but they didn't get expanded.

Comment: Daniel were you able to to reach a resolution for your issue? I'm running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Blue Ocean](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/blueocean/getting-started/). The UI view in my project where I'm using declarative pipeline looks like this:

[image: Blue Ocean UI]